# Use PHP to render multiple images to the browser

Tags: php, mysql

The code below renders one images to the browser in conjunction with my database, I want to display all of the image of the user, how should I amend the below code?

```
$coverpic = "";
$sql = "SELECT filename FROM photos WHERE user='$u'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $filename = $row[0];
    $coverpic = '<img src="user/'.$u.'/'.$filename.'" alt="pic">';
}
```

Comment: You got this far, what's stopping you going further?

Comment: side note: beware of `$u` (escape it, like http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php or see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). If you can, consider also http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thabks for the side not and F4r-20, am still getting to grips with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a while loop in to fetch the results.

```
$coverpic = '';
$sql = "SELECT filename FROM photos WHERE user='$u'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
      $filename = $row[0];
      $coverpic .= '<img src="user/'.$u.'/'.$filename.'" alt="pic">'; //notice the .= to append to the string instead of overwrite
   }

}
```

But if you want to make your code a little shorter with less checks:

```
$coverpic = '';
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT filename FROM photos WHERE user='$u'")){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
   $coverpic .= '<img src="user/'.$u.'/'.$row[0].'" alt="pic">';
}
```

Comment: In this case yes, but I still add it to be able to show something like 'No images found' in the else.

Comment: A big thank you man, would tick your answer as useful, yet I lack rep

Comment: @NoelVock you can mark the answer as accepted rather than upvote.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the downvote?

Comment: There is no point in having `if` just in case. You can always use `if` with negative condition instead of `else` once you need it. And your "shorter" code makes it worse. it will never show 'No images' actually

Comment: Thank you common sense. Damn i see the no images only shows when the query has an error. Didnt even know that. Glad I learned something today! To bad he felt my answer was completly invalid because of it and changed the accepted answer

Comment: Was an error but rectified

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
```

with

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
```

Comment: it is usually good if you explain why his example doesnt work, not just give answer. For example according to [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) mysqli_fetch_row  "fetches ONE ROW of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array" so you need to iterate with loop to get all results.